# Why does determining the nature of local extrema for $\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ functions require twice continuous-differentiability?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

[image]

In the text Elementary Classical Analysis, why does Marsden specify the condition "twice **continuously** differentiable" here? Isn't mere twice-differentiability sufficient for the purpose indicated?

I've just read the proof of this in another textbook, and the continuity of the second derivative doesn't seem to be necessary...

Comment: Most calculus texts don't really check each and every hypotheses in their theorems. Some even forget to check the result. For example, one book says that if $f$ is differentiable in $(a, b)$ and is strictly increasing then we must have $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$. But this is not the case we can only say $f'(x) \geq 0$ (check $f(x) = x^{3}$ in $(-1, 1)$). Thanks to these texts, everyone has to travel the road of confusion when learning calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just the author's ticks showing up. It is very standard in analysis to assume that a function has class $C^r$, i.e. that the $r$ first derivatives are continuous. This is just because this gives the space of functions whose $r$ derivatives exists a better structure when assuming continuity, but in this case for example it is not necessary to have it.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Maybe it's a misprint.